# bulk changing column types in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a PHP script where users create questionnaires, and the script tables in the DB to store the incoming data. The site's been live for a while, and there are about 100 tables in the database.

My script was awfully flawed! It calls for "tinytext" fields in places where I really need "text". Is there a way to bulk update all of the tinytext columns to text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Solution without stored procedures (using only phpMyAdmin or any other DBA tool).

Run the following query

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',
            TABLE_NAME,
            ' CHANGE COLUMN ',
            COLUMN_NAME,
            ' ',
            column_name,
            ' TARGET_TYPE ',
            CASE
                WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN ' NOT '
                ELSE ''
            END,
            ' NULL;') AS que
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    table_schema = 'MY DB'
        AND data_type = 'SOURCE_TYPE';
```

This query will return you all the statements to fire. You can run them or save into a SQL Upgrade script

Example (from tinyint to bit):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE COLUMN redacted redacted BIT  NULL;
ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE COLUMN redacted2 redacted2 BIT NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this, is to find all the `tinytext` columns in the given database and then create `ALTER TABLE` statement for the each column. Working solution using stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `BULK_RETYPE` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `BULK_RETYPE`(IN SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(255), IN FROM_TYPE VARCHAR(255), IN TO_TYPE VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE `done` INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE tn VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE fn VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE `cur1` CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        `TABLE_NAME`,
    `COLUMN_NAME`
    FROM
        `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
    WHERE
        `DATA_TYPE` = FROM_TYPE AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` = SCHEMA_NAME;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;


    OPEN cur1;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO `tn`, `fn`;
        IF done THEN
          LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

          SET @ALTER_SQL = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', '`', tn,'`' , ' MODIFY ', '`', fn,'`' , ' ', TO_TYPE);

          PREPARE stmt1 FROM @ALTER_SQL;
          EXECUTE stmt1;

    END LOOP;   
    CLOSE cur1; 
END $$

DELIMITER ;
CALL BULK_RETYPE('test', 'tinytext', 'text');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really, though if you use PHPMyAdmin, it's a rather quick task... alternatively, you could export a list of all the tables and fields you need to change and put together the necessary ALTER TABLE statements and then execute them.

Answer (score 0):

You can just select from schema and prepare SQL for mass alter

```
SELECT table_scheme, table_name, columun_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`
WHERE DATA_TYPE='tinyint'
```