# Getting range error when fetching PostgreSQL boolean field

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to convert PostgreSQL database to MySQL with MySQL Workbench tool. It seems that schema migration works fine - there are no errors, but when I'm trying to migrate data - I get huge list of errors and it looks like they all about the same thing - Postgres `boolean` field is fetched as extremely big integer number that can't be saved as `TINYINT` in MySQL:

```
ERROR: `mydb`.`my_table`:Range error fetching field 9 (value 140406775873536, target is MYSQL_TYPE_TINY)
```

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Please run migration wizard once again but in `Data Transfer Setup` step mark `Enable debug output for table copy` checkbox and then run data copy. After that upload log file to pastebin or so and provide link to it here.

Comment: @MiloszBodzek, there it is: http://pastebin.com/7ygiYN6U

Comment: meeting the same issue, @DmitryMikhaylov did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have a solution now.

**Reason:**

By default when migrate data from Postgres to MySQL using the wizard in MySQL Workbench, if the Postgres field is boolean, it will create TINYINT(1) column in MySQL, that's why we meet this error.

**Solution:**

1. alter the boolean field to INT

`ALTER TABLE`targetdb`.`sample_table`CHANGE COLUMN`fieldfield`INT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '' ;`

2. use MySQL Migration wizard will succeed.
3. alter the field back to TINYINT(1).

Comment: this is the first time ever I've googled a specific error that only returned 1 result on google, and it was the exact issue I was having, WITH a solution. even 6 years later this issue remains. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

If one of you guys has to do it on a large scale i suggest you take a look at this answer in order to generate a bulk script:

[bulk changing column types in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945513/bulk-changing-column-types-in-mysql)

or just check the script below :

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',
        TABLE_NAME,
        ' CHANGE COLUMN ',
        COLUMN_NAME,
        ' ',
        column_name,
        ' TARGET_TYPE ',
        CASE
            WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN ' NOT '
            ELSE ''
        END,
        ' NULL;') AS que
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    table_schema = 'MY DB'
    AND data_type = 'SOURCE_TYPE';
```